# When Ribbon button is clicked disable multiple buttons

Tags: vba, ms-access, ribbon

I have a couple of button is an MS access application that need to be enabled or disabled at the same time. When one of them is clicked and opens a form they both need to be set to disabled. When the form is closed they both need to be set to enabled.

I have no problem doing this for the control that is clicked. But I don't know how to reference the one that was not clicked.

Here is the code for my ribbon:

[image]

and the funciton I use to handle getEnabled:

[image]

**How do I disabled or enable both buttons at the same time?**

Comment: Post code as formatted text, not images.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [IRibbonUI.Invalidate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.iribbonui.invalidate) or [IRibbonUI.InvalidateControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.iribbonui.invalidatecontrol) methods to get your callback invoked for other controls. The invalidate method allows invalidating the cached values for all of the controls of the Ribbon user interface.

For example, if an add-in writer implements the `getImage` callback procedure for a button, the function is called once, the image loads, and then if the image needs to be updated, the cached image is used instead of recalling the procedure. This process remains in place until the add-in signals that the cached values are invalid by using the Invalidate method, at which time, the callback procedure is again called and the return response is cached. The add-in can then force an immediate update of the UI by calling the Refresh method.

```
Dim MyRibbon As IRibbonUI 
 
Sub MyAddInInitialize(Ribbon As IRibbonUI) 
 Set MyRibbon = Ribbon 
End Sub 
 
Sub myFunction() 
 MyRibbon.Invalidate() ' Invalidates the caches of all of this add-in's controls 
End Sub
```

The Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) is described in depth in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)